# Google Optimize A/B testing

Tags: google-analytics, visual-editor, google-optimize

I would like to do a A/B testing on the registration process of my website, so testing a new registration funnel and see if it improves register customers/new deposited customer. Is it possible to test such a big change in Google Optimize? i.e. change the whole implementation of the site.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Is your registration process made of multiple pages with completely different URLs? If not, you can do 'Redirect test' in Google Optimize, setting a custom URL or just GET parameter, for variant you want to test. For example, if your original registration URL looks like `/registration`, you could add `/registration-new` URl which can serve as a variant of the test.

[Here's link on detailed instructions on how to setup redirect test](https://support.google.com/optimize/answer/6361119?hl=en).